# javascript Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript

I have the following url

```
http://www.test.info/?id=50&size=40
```

How do I get the value of the url parameter with regular expressions in javascript . i need the size value and also need the url without &?

only

```
http://www.test.info/?id=50
```

Thanks

Comment: no not the id parameter  i need the value after  & like size=40

Comment: and need the url without &  like http://www.test.info/?id=50

Comment: this is Exactly what you need, look at that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `split` instead of a regex:

```
var splitted = 'http://www.test.info/?id=50&size=40'.split('&');
var urlWithoutAmpersand = splitted[0];
// now urlWithoutAmpersand => 'http://www.test.info/?id=50'
var sizeValue = splitted[1].split('=')[1] * 1;
// now sizeValue => 40
```

Comment: does not answer question. Your solution is neither a regex, nor does it provide the value of the size param.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel I edited my answer, but anyway, isn't it ok to suggest a different wayof doing it?

Comment: your answer is better, but it would break if any additional parameters are added. And yes, it's ok to provide various solutions... if they answer the question.

Comment: You're right, but reading his question, I'm not sure if he needs a generic solution...

Answer (score 0):

Just use this as your regex

```
size.*?(?=&|$)
```

here is some code you can use

```
var re = /size.*?(?=&|$)/g;
var myArray = url.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
```

you also can do it like this:

```
var re = new RegExp("size.*?(?=&|$)", "g");
```

Comment: that will also grab anything trailing AFTER the size param, even additional params.

Comment: what you think now ?

Comment: Much better. I would add that the "size" match must be preceded by ?|& as well, since you dont want a match from the url portion

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex pattern you could use.

```
^(.+)&size=(\d+)
```

The first group will be the url up to right before the '&' sign. The second group will be the value of the size parameter. This assumes id always comes before size, and that there are only two parameters: id and size.